# HTML5 Video Play/Pause control is not working in safari browser only

Tags: macos, video, safari, html5-video

Pause/play control of HTML5 video does not working as expected in safari browser. It is working fine in other browsers. Please help me on this.

After clicking the pause mode icon, video is still playing. When I click a mute icon, video is stopped/playing vice versa. Attached image for reference.

[Video controls Image as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM6Ja.jpg)

```
<video controls id="video-gpro">
       <source src="@Model.Manualvideo" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Following error is displaying in console when clicked the play/pause icon.

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: [Object DOMError]
>   N (anonymous function)
>   N rejectPromise

Comment: "is not working as expected".
Please describe what it does, what you expect it to do and how those two differ. "doesnt work" is a rather bad problem description.

Comment: Updated description Fabian Schöner

Comment: That's unusual. Error logged?

Comment: Are there any custom javascripts regarding controlling the video in any way in your environment? If you put your video tag as it is in a stackoverflow snippet in here, does it still show the wrong behaviour?

Comment: Updated console error

Comment: @vinothkumar102 maybe this does help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431439/mp4-video-safari-showing-unhandled-promise-rejection-object-domerror-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @FabianSchöner I tried the given link approach. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles upon this error with context that is in description
Check out [Google Article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted#danger-zone)

Basically no `<source>` tag inside `<video>`